# How to allow WordPress editors (role) to put code in WYSIWSG textarea?

Tags: wordpress, xcode, input, roles

In WordPress, I have a custom field where I need some editors (WordPress role) to put some html+javascript code.
It seems that WordPress clean the code when you're not an administrator.
Is there a hook or option that I can edit in order to let them add those codes (embed, forms, ...)?

I tried to put some javascript code with the admin role, ok.
I tried with editor role, ko.

So, I'm pretty sure the problem comes from there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after further review and a look in wordpress core functions, here's the answer.

In multisite, editors don't have 'unfiltered_html' capability.
So you just have to had it:

```
<?php
function add_custom_capability_to_editors( $caps, $cap, $user_id ) {
if ( 'unfiltered_html' === $cap && user_can( $user_id, 'editor' ) ) {
    $caps = array( 'unfiltered_html' );
}
return $caps;
}
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'add_custom_capability_to_editors', 1, 3 );
```